# Laravel - check if routes on blade

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I need to check 2 routes, and if one is true, add some content

```
@if (Route::current()->uri() != '/' || Route::current()->uri() != 'login')<div>add some content some contnt </div> @endif
```

I have tried with '||' and 'OR' and 'or'. I have also tried with `Request::path()`, which works only when checking 1 route

```
@if (Route::current()->uri() != '/') <div>add some content some contnt </div> @endif
```

If I try 2 routes it doesn't seem to work

Comment: the if statement looks fine to me. Should work. Please note that you are checking if NOT root or if NOT login. What is the URL shown in your address bar when you observed it was not working?

Answer (score 35):

You can use the built in methods to check for a route name or pattern.

See `Route::is()` or `Route::currentRouteNamed()`

For example:

```
Route::get('users', 'Controller..')->name('users.index');
Route::get('users/{id}', 'Controller..')->name('users.show');
```

Assuming you are in the following path : `users/1`

```
@if(Route::is('users.show') )
    // true
@endif

@if(Route::is('users') )
    // false
@endif

@if(Route::is('users.*') )
    // true
@endif
```

So in your example try `@if(Route::is('home') or Route::is('login'))..@endif`

Comment: It should be Route::currentRouteName() instead of Route::currentRouteNamed().

Comment: You could also use `currentRouteName` but the difference is that this method returns a string (route name) or null, on the other hand, `currentRouteNamed` accepts argument of patterns and returns a boolean. 
https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/e57fbd2e9e0606d17e0ca128bcef8b6b3fc2d556/Router.php#L1274

Answer (score 7):

You could also do:

`request()->routeIs('categories')`
or
`request()->routeIs(['categories', 'services'])`

Answer (score 4):

Try using route names instead. In your web.php file put this:

```
Route::get('/')->name('home');
Route::get('/login')->name('login');
```

And then change your if condition to this:

```
@if (Route::currentRouteName() != 'home' || Route::currentRouteName() != 'login')
<div>add some content some contnt </div> 
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your condition right because you're comparing between url and string.
Try this plz:

```
URL::current() != url('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use routes names and `in_array` instead...

In your web.php

```
Route::get('/', ...)->name('home');
Route::get('/login', ...)->name('login');
```

Then you can do something like this

```
in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['home', 'login'])
```